# Querydsl - register custom types in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, querydsl

I am trying to register my custom type in querydsl metadata exporter.

I have enum like this:

```
public enum RoleName {
    ADMIN, USER;
}
```

Then, I created my custom type for querydsl:

```
public class RoleNameType extends EnumByNameType<RoleName> {
    public RoleNameType(Class<RoleName> type) {
        super(type);
    }
}
```

My querydsl plugin setup in pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>export</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <jdbcDriver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</jdbcDriver>
                <jdbcUrl>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</jdbcUrl>
                <jdbcUser>user</jdbcUser>
                <jdbcPassword>pass</jdbcPassword>
                <packageName>com.example</packageName>
                <targetFolder>target/generated-sources/java</targetFolder>
                <namePrefix>BLANK</namePrefix>
                <schemaPattern>TASK_MANAGER_USER</schemaPattern>
                <customTypes>
                    <customType>com.example.RoleNameType</customType>
                </customTypes>
                <typeMappings>
                    <typeMapping>
                        <table>TM_ROLE</table>
                        <column>ROLE_NAME</column>
                        <type>com.example.RoleName</type>
                    </typeMapping>
                </typeMappings>
                <numericMappings>
                    <numericMapping>
                        <total>1</total>
                        <decimal>0</decimal>
                        <javaType>java.lang.Boolean</javaType>
                    </numericMapping>
                </numericMappings>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
                    <version>10.2.0.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

During building exception is returned:
"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.RoleNameType"

I already checked that there is no typo in package or class names. 
Any ideas how to use querydsl metadata exporter together with my custom enum?

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a solution to your problem, but maybe it helps to come to a faster conclusion for anyone else bumping into this issue:

I wanted to do the same thing which you've described and failed in the same way. After some time of trying and browsing the web I came across the querydsl Github project's issue [#1865](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1865). @timowest's reply states that the project's sources are not part of the plugin's classpath. Hence, the exporter is not able to find the class specified in the type mapping which leads to the ClassNotFoundException.

He also stated that the project's dependencies are available in the classpath. I thought, I give it a try and extracted my enums putting them in a separate module within my project. The new module was added as a dependency to my original module. Unfortunately, the outcome was the same: A ClassNotFoundException was thrown, eventhough, the enum module appeared on the classpath checking Maven's debug output.

@timowest responded on that issue in 2016 and closed the issue as resolved. I didn't find any indication that it was actually resolved. So, I assume, there is no easy solution. The project seems to be inactive since one year, anyway.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response! Actually I made it work some time ago, but didn't have time to provide a solution. It looks like we did the same thing by putting enums into separate module like in your description. I remember I had to add dependency for module with enums in two places: in original maven module, and also in dependencies for querydsl-maven-plugin. I will try to find my test project and provide full answer.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for getting back to me. Setting the dependency in the plugin itself was the bit that was missing. Now, it's working for me as well. Feel free to add this as the correct answer.